# why does this python program automatically close?

Tags: python

this program quits after printing the first line and seemingly doesn't enter the while loop. i'm at a dead end here, any help would be appreciated. it's design is to create files with the same name at different directories

```
print ("What is the name of the command to create?: ")
#loops until program is done
exit = "placeholder"
while exit != exit:
#filename to use for directory creation
    cmd = input()
#combines cmd name with directory
    cmdDir = "/usr/bin/" + cmd
#makes sure something was entered as a cmd name
    if cmdDir == "/usr/bin/":
        print ("Command name invalid. Try again: ")

    else: 
#creates file at directory with cmd name
        open (cmdDir, 'a')
            print ("Will this command have a python extension?: ")
#loops until program is done
            while exit != exit:
                decision = input()
#combines cmd name with python directory
                pythonDir = "/root/python/" + cmd + ".py"
                if decision == "yes":
#creates directory              
                    open (pythonDir, 'a')
                    print ("Command directories " + cmdDir + " and" + pythonDir + " created. ")
#sets program to exit while loops
                    exit = "exit"
                elif decision == "no":
                    print ("Command directory " + cmdDir + "created. ")
#sets program to exit while loops
                    exit = "exit"
                else:
                    print ("Enter yes or no: ")
```

ps: formatting this manually with the 4-space indent was a pain in the ass, how does the auto-indent work?

Comment: `while exit != exit:`; What do you think this is doing?

Comment: while exit != exit: => should be while exit != "exit":

Comment: exit is equal to exit and hence exit!=exit means false.

Comment: Autoindent: Highlight the code block and press Ctrl-K. Check out [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: ack.. that's what it was. forgot fkn quotes.

Comment: Either you kicked your pet donkey because you were frustrated or you're using `ass` in the context where we Aussies would use `arse` (a much better-sounding, butteral, term and one that avoids confusion, IMNSHO). If the latter, it's potentially going to offend _someone_ so you may want to be careful :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
while exit != exit:
```

`exit` will *always* be equal to `exit`, since they're the same variable (there are exceptions to this rule in certain circumstances but not for a string type in Python). So that expression will always be false and you'll never enter the body of the loop.

You probably meant to do this instead:

```
while exit != 'exit':
```

which compares the *variable* with a fixed string *constant.*

Answer (score 0):

```
while exit != exit:
```

is what is messing you up. Since they are the same variable `exit` will always equal `exit`. Since `exit` is a string there are no ways around this.

So the code you might wanna use could be `while exit != 'exit':` This will stop the program from exiting on line 1. The reason for this is that if the variable `exit` doesn't have the value of `'exit'` then the program will run.

Hope this helps.